# Ideals generated by two elements in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

Consider the following ideal $(2+x,x^2+5)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then I showed that $(2+x,x^2+5)=(9,2+x)$.

But I am not able to do the same for ideals $(1-4x,x^2+5)$ and $(1+2x,x^2+5)$.
Is there some method?

**EDIT:** My goal is to show that these ideals can be written as $(c,ax+b)$ for some appropriate integers $a,b,c$.

Would be very grateful for help!

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @AndresMejia, sorry, didn't understand your question?

Comment: "I am not able to do the same..." what is "the same?"

Comment: @AndresMejia, I would like to show that these ideals is something like $(c,ax+b)$. Is it clear right now?

Comment: yep! thanks :)${}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\bmod I=(x^2\!+\!5,\,1\!-\!4x)\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{4x\equiv 1}\,$ so $\,0\equiv 4(x^2\!+\!5)\equiv (\color{#c00}{4x})x\!+\!20\equiv x\!+\!20$

Equivalently $I$ contains $\,4(x^2\!+\!5)+x(1\!-\!4x) = 20\!+\!x$

Since $\,x\!+\!20\in I\,$ we can further reduce mod $\,x\!+\!20\,$ too, i.e. use $\,\color{#0a0}{x\equiv -20}\,$ to evaluate / reduce all other generators via $\,f(\color{#0a0}x)\equiv f(\color{#0a0}{-20}),\ $ i.e. we have 
$$({x\!-\!a},\, f,\,g) = (x\!-\!a,\, f\bmod{x\!-\!\color{#0a0}a},\,g\bmod{x\!-\!\color{#0a0}a}) = (x\!-\!a,f(\color{#0a0}a),g(\color{#0a0}a))\qquad$$

just like in the euclidean algorithm $\, (a,b) = (a,\,b\bmod a).\ $  In summary it is simply:

$$(1\!-\!4x,\,x^2\!+\!5) = (x\!+\!20,\,\underbrace{1\!-\!4x}_{\large f(x)},\,\underbrace{x^2\!+\!5}_{\large g(x)}) = (x\!+\!20,\!\!\underbrace{81}_{\!\!\!\!\large f(-20)},\!\underbrace{405}_{\large g(-20)}\!\!) = (x\!+\!20,81)$$

**Corollary** $\ f\bmod I\, =\, f(-20)\bmod 81,\ $ so $\ f\in I\iff 81\mid f(-20)$

Comment: Dear, Bill! Could you clarify it with words? I don't understand it :( Why $4x \equiv 1$?

Comment: the trick is to do it modulo $1-4x$. In the quotient $\mathbb Z[x]/(1-4x)$, we have that $4x-1 \equiv 0$ or $4x \equiv 1$.

Comment: @ZFR $\equiv$ is used to mean equality in a quotient ring.

Comment: It is not clear how are you working with modulo? Why $4x\equiv 1$ and it is not clear the rest of your answer.

Comment: @ZFR $\,f\in I\iff f\equiv 0\pmod I\ $ so we can work mod $I$ to find other elements (e.g. generators) of $I$ $\ \ $

Comment: Thanks a lot I got! You showed that $x+20 \in (1-4x,x^2+5)$. But how to get the desired form $(c,ax+b)$?

Comment: @ZFR By $\,x\!+\!20\in I\,$ now you can reduce mod $\,x\!+\!20\,$ too, i.e. use $\,x\equiv -20\,$ to evaluate / reduce all other generators via $\,f(x)\equiv f(-20)\ \ $

Comment: @ZFR Well, since both $x+20$ and $1-4x$ are elements of $I$, can you find an integer which is an element of $I$?

Comment: @Arthur, Yes, $81=4(x+20)+(1-4x)$

Comment: @Arthur, Am I right that $(x^2+5,1-4x)=(x+20,1-4x)$? For example, I have shown that $(x+20,1-4x)\subseteq (x^2+5,1-4x)$. But how to show inverse inclusion?

Comment: @ZFR $\,(x\!-\!a, f(x),g(x)) = (x\!-\!a,f(a),g(a))\ $ by $\, f(x)\equiv f(a)\pmod {x\!-\!a},\,$ just like in Euclid's algorithm (prove it!)

Comment: @BillDubuque, how the last equality refers to question? Could you show it in detail, please? Cause I can not understand the essence of your answer.

Comment: @ZfF In your case you have $\,a = -20,\  f(x) = x^2+5,\ g(x) = 1-4x\ \ $

Comment: @ZFR I added a summary to my answer. Hopefully that helps to bring it all together.

Comment: I have noticed that in this example $f(-20)\mid g(-20)$. Is this always true?

Comment: @ZFR Here $\,4(x^2\!+\!5) = -x(1\!-\!4x) + 20\!+\!x\in (1\!-\!4x,20\!+\!x) =: J.\,$ But $4$ is a unit (invertible) mod $J$ so $\,4(x^2\!+\!5)\in J\,\Rightarrow\, x^2\!+\!5\in J.\,$ So we could have removed $\,g = x^2\!+\!5\,$ before evaluating. Note $\,81=f(-20)\mid g(-20)\,$ is true for all $\,g\in I,\,$ see the Corollary in the answer.

Comment: Big thanks for your answer! I have learnt something useful :)

Comment: @ZFR Glad it was helpful. Alas, most textbooks don't explain things like this very well (if at all), since it's a bit too advanced for elementary books, but a bit too elementary for advanced books. So I try to highlight these ideas here to help fill the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\langle 1-4x,x^2+5\rangle=\langle x+20,81\rangle$.  This is because
$$x^2+5=(x-20)\cdot(x+20)+5\cdot 81\,,$$
$$1-4x=(-4)\cdot (x+20)+1\cdot 81\,,$$
$$x+20=4\cdot(x^2+5)+x\cdot(1-4x)\,,$$
and
$$81=16\cdot(x^2+5)+(1+4x)\cdot(1-4x)\,.$$

Similarly, $\langle 1-2x,x^2+5\rangle=\langle x+10,21\rangle$.  This is because
$$x^2+5=(x-10)\cdot(x+10)+5\cdot 21\,,$$
$$1-2x=(-2)\cdot(x+10)+1\cdot 21\,,$$
$$x+10=2\cdot(x^2+5)+x\cdot(1-2x)\,,$$
and
$$21=4\cdot(x^2+5)+(1+2x)\cdot(1-2x)\,.$$

Comment: Good! but how you come up with those coefficients? The most difficult for me was finding the appropriate coefficients.

Comment: My first goal was to find an integer $c$ that is definitely in the ideal.  You want to eliminate $x^2$ from $x^2+5$.  Say, your linear polynomial is $1-2x$.  A multiple of $1-2x$ that only has $x^2$ and a constant term is $(1+2x)\cdot(1-2x)$.  This calculation leads to the last line of each case.

Comment: To find a linear polynomial $ax+b$ that is in the ideal is similar.  You want to eliminate $x^2$ from $x^2+5$, but you want to leave the terms of order $1$ and $0$.  A multiple of $1-2x$ that can eliminate $x^2$ from $x^2+5$ but leave a term of order $1$ is $x\cdot(1-2x)$.  This is the calculation in the second-to-last line of each case.

Comment: I want to note that you can't just use $1-2x$ for $ax+b$.  It turns out that $\langle 21,1-2x\rangle$ is not the same as $\langle 1-2x,x^2+5\rangle$.  If $|a|\neq 1$, then you can never generate a monic polynomial $x^2+5$.  Thus, the end result should have $a=1$ (or $a=-1$, but the sign doesn't really matter).